# .Load IE not working

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a Montage Theme and I have one massive IE bug, I think its a image .Load problem. I've tried adding .Load events to the images so they work once the page has loaded. I've also tried playing around with image cached scripts.

This is a sample of information that is in the montage.js document

```
// $('#my-container').imagesLoaded(myFunction)
// execute a callback when all images have loaded.
// needed because .load() doesn't work on cached images
```

I've tried playing around with imageLoaded but have had no look.

This is my current code,

```
<!-- Montage Requirments -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/montage.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var $container  = $('#am-container'),
        $imgs       = $container.find('img').hide();
 $(window).load(function() {
        $imgs.show();
        $container.montage({
            fillLastRow : true,
            alternateHeight : true,
            alternateHeightRange : {
                min : 150,
                max : 250
            },
            margin : 0
        });
    });

});
        </script>
<!-- Montage Finished -->
```

URL: http://www.media21a.co.uk/development/unknown/

Comment: Try with `$(document).load()` instead.

Comment: The plain JavaScript `onload` event works just fine on cached images, jsyk.

Comment: Tried document .load this stop the Montage from working all together (all browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Wordpress' no conflict wrappers?

Comment: I've tryed playing around with no conflict but this seems not to be working could you have a check that it looks right http://www.media21a.co.uk/development/unknown/ ... any over suggestions would be great ?